# what is the proper way to force chef to execute a recipe?

Tags: chef

I have a chef script which is doing

```
directory '/home/ubuntu/s3' do
  action :create  
end

execute 'copy from s3' do
  command "aws s3 cp s3://my-assets /home/ubuntu/s3/ --recursive"    
end
```

...

I noticed after copying a new file to my s3 bucket, it was not on my server after running this chef recipe...  So then I ssh'd into the server and rm -rf'd the s3 directory..  Re-ran my chef script, and it failed later on when trying to access something in the s3 directory saying "no file or directory."

I ssh'd back in and found that chef never recreated the directory after I deleted it...  So......  How do I tell chef to redo the stuff that it thinks it's already done and doesn't need to do?

Answer (score 0):

The resource inside a recipe aren't necessarily in order.

Try:

```
directory '/home/ubuntu/s3' do
  action :create  
end

execute 'copy from s3' do
  command "aws s3 cp s3://my-assets /home/ubuntu/s3/ --recursive" 
  only_if { ::Dir.exist?(/home/ubuntu/s3) }
end
```

or:

```
directory '/home/ubuntu/s3' do                                                                                                                                                  
  action :create..                                                                                                                                                              
end                                                                                                                                                                             

execute 'copy from s3' do                                                                                                                                                       
  command "aws s3 cp s3://my-assets /home/ubuntu/s3/ --recursive".                                                                                                              
  subscribes :create, "directory[/home/ubuntu/s3]"                                                                                                                              
end
```